# eclipse does not step in method

Tags: eclipse, remote-debugging

For some reason, when  I tried to step into a method when it's highlighted, it just skips over it and it does not step into it.

It does not happen for all methods, only some.

Why does it do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The step into will work with all methods. Only the restriction is, you must have execution suspended and be stepping through code. I think, a Eclipse restart will fix your issue.

**Note:** Also cross check the classes that allowing step filters.

Comment: Yes, basically it hits a breakpoint and as I step through the break point, I tried to step into a method, it does not do. It actually even goes to to weird line numbers where a conditional statement should not allow the program to enter.  For example, I have a boolean variable for an if condition.  The code would go into the if if statement only when it is true.  Yet, the program execution goes into the if statement even when the it is false (I inspect it using eclipse and it shows me false).  I don't know why the program enter the statement.  Maybe my source and compiled code are no in sync\

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- make sure the "Build Automatically" is ticked (Project->Build Automatically)
- make sure you have debugging enabled (Window->Preferences->Java->Run/Debug: and check "Activate the workbench when a breakpoint is hit" is ticked
- make sure you are running the app in debug mode (Right click class/project Debug As->Java application)
- make sure your code is being compiled/deployed when you save the file

If you are debugging on a j2ee server (tomcat/seam) then these containers usually have their own debugging options so be sure to check them also!

Good luck!

Comment: This is a remote debug session. Your comments are not relevant.